# Duvida com RegEx com nova linha

Tags: regex, notepad++

Criei a seguinte expressão:

```
"<strike>.*?</strike>"
```

para pegar todo o texto taxado, mas devido ao código fonte ter quebra de linha (como no ex. a baixo) não está dando certo.

```
<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0"><a name="6"></a><strike>Art. 
6º São direitos sociais a educação, a saúde, o
trabalho, o lazer, a segurança, a previdência social, a proteção à maternidade e à
infância, a assistência aos desamparados, na forma desta Constituição.</strike></p>

<p style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">
<strike><a name="art6"></a>Art.     6<sup>o</sup> São direitos sociais a educação, a saúde, o
trabalho, a moradia, o lazer, a segurança, a previdência social, a proteção à
maternidade e à infância, a assistência aos desamparados, na forma desta
Constituição.<a href="Emendas/Emc/emc26.htm#1">(Redação dada pela Emenda
Constitucional nº 26, de 2000)</a></strike></p>
```

Estou usando o `regex` no localizar do Notepad++.

Como faço para o `regex` pegar também a quebra de linha?

Comment: Isso vai depender da sua linguagem de programação.

Comment: Qual linguagem você está usando e como está instanciando sua expressão regular?

Comment: não estou usando nenhuma linguagem, mas o notepad++

Comment: Essa informação é muito importante, pois a sintaxe muda conforme o ambiente que vais utilizar a expressão regular.

Comment: Quando você tiver uma resposta, poste como resposta. No caso, você encontrou uma solução, elabore uma resposta explicando qual a solução e, se não for naturalmente claro, explicando porque soluciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta marcar a caixinha **". considerar quebra de linha"**.

Veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

A maioria das engines usa o `.` como *"qualquer caractere exceto quebra de linha"*. Usualmente existe a opção `m`, que liga o modo multilinha e remove a restrição no `.`. Geralmente a sintaxe é essa:

```
/<strike>.*?</strike>/m
```

Mas varia de linguagem para linguagem e de cada implementação. Olhe a documentação da engine que você está a usar para mais detalhes.

Answer (score 3):

Isso depende da linguagem que você está executando. Cada uma tem uma forma de especificar que o ponto deve incluir caracteres de final de linha.

O conceito de *dot all* faz com que o ponto considere as quebras de linha, mas não podemos esquecer de que por padrão algumas linguagens não interpretam várias linhas, então devemos especificar que a expressão é *multiline*.

### Java

Em Java você acrescenta `java.util.regex.Pattern.DOTALL` e `java.util.regex.Pattern.MULTILINE` ao criar o `Pattern`:

```java
Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.MULTILINE + Pattern.DOTALL);
```

### Javascript

Em Javascript não existe, mas segundo essa resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068280/javascript-regex-multiline-flag-doesnt-work) você pode usar `[\s\S]` ao invés do ponto para atingir o mesmo objetivo.

- `\s` inclui espaços em branco, incluindo quebras de linha e tabulações
- `\S` inclui o que não é espaço em branco (o oposto)

Logo, `[\s\S]` inclui todos os caracteres.

### PHP

Em PHP você pode usar os modificadores `s` (*dotall*) e `m` (multiline). Exemplo: .

```php
<?php
$subject = "abcdef";
$pattern = ''/(.*)/sm'';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

### Python

Em Python temos as constantes `re.DOTALL` e `re.MULTILINE`:

```py
import re
regex = re.compile(pattern, flags = re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: +1 na sua e na do Bernal. Ainda que a pergunta dele seja para o Notepad++, logo logo essa pergunta aqui vai ser indexada pelo Google, e sabemos o que vai acontecer.

Comment: "*algumas linguagens não interpretam várias linhas, então devemos especificar que a expressão é multiline.*" <- Isto está errado... Java, JavaScript, PHP ou Python não têm problema com várias linhas... Multiline só altera o comportamento de `^` e `$` para corresponder com o início / fim da linha em vez do início / fim da string. E você não precisa da flag Multiline neste caso. Veja https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#multi

Answer (score 1):

a expressão que satisfaz a condição ficou assim

```
 <strike>(.|\n)*?</strike>
```

também dava pra usar a expressão que citei anteriormente :

```
<strike>.*?</strike>
```

e marcar no modo de busca do localizar o checkbox ". maches newline"